# Material-UI Drawer acts different on tablets

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I'm getting some weird problems with the Material-UI drawer component. It scrolls horizontal on my iPad, compared to my MacBook and Android Phone, which actually scroll vertically..

### Result on MacBook *(how it's supposed to be..)*:

[image: MacBook Image]
As you can see, it scrolls down and it overflows vertically, just like on my phone

### Result on iPad *(how it's not supposed to be..)*:

[image: iPad Image]
However, as you can see.. on my iPad it overflows horizontally..?

#### The code for the drawer:

```js
<Drawer
  anchor="right"
  open={open}
  onClose={HandleClose}
  classes={{ paper: classes.drawerPaper }}>
    <Toolbar />
      <Typography className={classes.title}>Selecteer actieve regio's</Typography>
      <FormControl component="fieldset" className={classes.formControl}>
        <FormGroup>
          {regios.map(regio => (
            <FormControlLabel
              control={
                <Checkbox
                  checked={geselecteerdeRegios.includes(regio.ID)}
                  onChange={e => handleRegioChange(regio.ID, e.target.checked)}
                />
              }
              name={regio.Naam}
              label={regio.Naam}
              key={regio.Naam}
            />
         ))}
    </FormGroup>
  </FormControl>
</Drawer>
```

#### And these are the styles for the drawer

```js
drawerPaper: {
  width: 320
},
```

Why is this happening? And how can I prevent this and only allow vertical scroll/overflow instead of horizontal..?

Edit: codesandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-khayyam-t6klg?file=/src/Drawer.js

Thanks in advance! :-)

Comment: If you provide an example via codesandbox.io or similar it would be much easier to help you.

Comment: I added it to the subject

Comment: Does the example you provided also behave the same on your ipad?

Comment: Yes, it does for me

Comment: Which generation is your iPad? The bug might be because of an old version of the browser (Safari).

Comment: I'm using the 2018 iPad, with the Brave browser (it's based on chromium AFAIK)

Comment: Please try a different browser and report the results.

Comment: I used Safari, same result..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be related to the [default styles](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.11/packages/material-ui/src/FormGroup/FormGroup.js#L11) on `FormGroup`:

```
  /* Styles applied to the root element. */
  root: {
    display: 'flex',
    flexDirection: 'column',
    flexWrap: 'wrap',
  },
```

You can override this to `nowrap` to prevent the wrapping (as shown below with `classes.formGroup` in a modified version of your sandbox). I have not taken the time to understand why this behaves differently on iPads than on other devices.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Drawer,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  FormControlLabel,
  Checkbox,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
  makeStyles
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  drawerPaper: {
    width: 320
  },
  formGroup: {
    flexWrap: "nowrap"
  }
}));

export default () => {
  let items = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) items.push("foobarfazboo" + i);

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Drawer anchor="right" open={true} classes={{ paper: classes.drawerPaper }}>
      <Toolbar />
      <Typography className={classes.title}>
        Selecteer actieve regio's
      </Typography>
      <FormControl component="fieldset" className={classes.formControl}>
        <FormGroup className={classes.formGroup}>
          {items.map(item => (
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox />}
              name={item}
              label={item}
              key={item}
            />
          ))}
        </FormGroup>
      </FormControl>
    </Drawer>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Drawer wrap]

Unfortunately, this still leaves some odd behavior on the iPad. It seems to try to fit all of the content in the `Drawer` without scrolling (e.g. if I add 100 items instead of 25, they still are all forced to fit and become an unreadable, squished mess).

I don't fully understand what is happening, but it appears to be an interplay between the `height` and `display: flex` on the `Drawer` `Paper`. Changing the display from `flex` to `block` fixes this. I don't see any obvious new problems caused by this, but I haven't taken a lot of time to look at what other effects this change causes. With this change, the above "nowrap" change appears unnecessary.

```
import React from "react";
import {
  Drawer,
  FormControl,
  FormGroup,
  FormControlLabel,
  Checkbox,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
  makeStyles
} from "@material-ui/core";

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
  drawerPaper: {
    width: 320,
    display: "block"
  }
}));

export default () => {
  let items = [];

  for (let i = 0; i < 25; i++) items.push("foobarfazboo" + i);

  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <Drawer anchor="right" open={true} classes={{ paper: classes.drawerPaper }}>
      <Toolbar />
      <Typography className={classes.title}>
        Selecteer actieve regio's
      </Typography>
      <FormControl component="fieldset" className={classes.formControl}>
        <FormGroup>
          {items.map(item => (
            <FormControlLabel
              control={<Checkbox />}
              name={item}
              label={item}
              key={item}
            />
          ))}
        </FormGroup>
      </FormControl>
    </Drawer>
  );
};
```

[image: Edit Drawer wrap]

Comment: Thank you, this worked.. However now I don't have any vertical spacing between the items, and if I add a vertical margin that also appears on my other devices but on top of the default margin, so doubled. How would I be able to have vertical spacing on my iPad?

Comment: @Nurfey It doesn't seem to be a matter of vertical margin. It seems that on the iPad, it is forcing all the content to fit without scrolling. I'll add to my answer momentarily.

Comment: @Nurfey I've added an alternative solution.

Comment: Thank you very much for your extensive help!